# C++11 noexcept qualifier and inline methods

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, inline, noexcept

Does C++11 give any guarantees about `inline` functions or methods, when they make calls to other functions declared with the `noexcept` qualifier?

```
class My_String { ...

    const char * c_str () const noexcept;
    inline operator const char * () const { return c_str(); }
};
```

I assume an optimizing compiler would be free to implement the inline method without full EH and stack unwinding, as per the `noexcept` qualification. I would also expect this for a simple accessor method too:

```
... inline operator const char * () const { return m_buffer; }
```

While this example looks trivial, exception guarantees matter when used to implement other classes or functions. **Q:** Does the C++11 standard address this or should inline methods be marked `noexcept`? Or is it better to omit `noexcept` unless *required* to match a class or function specification?

**Edit:** To avoid some confusion: Is `noexcept` implicit for the inline method?

Comment: For user provided code, `noexcept` is only implicit for destructors, as a simple answer.

Comment: a follow-on question is: **should one declare `noexcept` whenever possible?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, no.  The only implicit exception-specifications are

- On destructors.
- On other implicitly declared or explicitly defaulted special member functions: default constructors, copy and move constructors, and copy and move assignment, when not declared in a class definition, or declared with `= default;`.
- On deallocation functions: `operator delete` and `operator delete[]`.

[Note that for deallocation functions, an implicit exception-specification is always as if `noexcept(true)`.  For all destructors, and for special member functions which are implicitly declared or explicitly defaulted on the first declaration, the implicit exception-specification can be either `noexcept(true)` or `noexcept(false)`, as determined from the exception-specifications of the corresponding special member functions of any base classes and members of class type.]

So with either example declaration, `noexcept(static_cast<const char*>(std::declval<const MyString>()))` must be `false`.  Go ahead and write `noexcept` where it might matter.

Of course, as you noted, a compiler optimization is still allowed to notice an inline function can't throw exceptions and simplify exception handling in the caller.

Comment: In the list of *implicit `noexcept`* you are missing that  destructors that are used declared/defined are implicitly `noexcept` unless the user provided a different exception specification. This is a deviation of C++11 from C++03 behavior. That is, a user declared destructor like `T::~T() { throw 1; }` will terminate the program even if no other exception is active (note the lack of exception specification)

Comment: Also missed in the original answer: explicitly defaulted special members act the same as if implicitly declared.

Comment: Also, while I understand what you are saying (and agree) I am not sure if this is going to be all so clear for readers that don't already *know* it. Implicitly declared member functions will not be *always* implicitly `noexcept`. The compiler must generate the exception specification from the definition of the members. That is, a class that holds a member of a type whose constructor is `noexcept(false)` will have an implicitly declared destructor `noexcept(false)`. A class with a user declared destructor will also have the exception specification derived in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks. The use of `noexcept(expr)` is something I've avoided, but it's nice to know this information is available at compile time, like the `<type_traits>` functionality.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Years late, but I added a bit clarifying that implicit exception-specification does not always mean non-throwing specification.